# Add custom version to an image

Tags: images, thumbnails, header-image, retina

I have scoured the web for plugins and articles to help me solve something that seems pretty basic, but couldn't find anything.

I want a way to create custom versions, particularly sizes, of an image on a per-image basis.

I know I can register a specific size of image and WP will create it for every image that is uploaded.

But what I want is to be able to create a scaled version of an existing image from the media library UI.

For example, let's say I upload image A. WP creates a version by default that is 600px wide and I use it at that size throughout the website.

But then I have a call-to-action box in an article where I want to display the image, but with a width of 175px.

So, I want to create a version of that image at the 175px width, as well as a retina 2x 350px wide.

When I add the image to the box, I want WP to output a srcset that includes those two additional sizes so that the browser can pick whichever image it thinks is best for the situation.

I don't want to specify those 175px and 350px as additional image sizes for ALL images, because I won't need it for most of them.

This seems like a pretty common use-case to me, but despite that I couldn't find anything.

Perhaps I am using the wrong keywords and I hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

so you can do that in 2  different  ways 
1. modify   directly on template-parts/content-single.php
2. you can plug it  using the

```
add_action(pre_get_post,func_with_your_staff )
```

inside this

```
    function func_with_your_staff( $query ) {
        global $wp ; 
     if ( $query->is_single() && empty($query->post_type) $query->set('post_type', 'wherever_is_type'); // perhaps you have a custom_post_type 
    ?> and then you can add your extra staff <img src"" class="big-img"> <?
}
```

3. you can use jQuery(myImg).css('width','600px')